# Retrieving data using PDO connection

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to learn PHP OOP concept and has a database connection using PDO as below:

```
class db{
private $host;
private $user;
private $pass;
private $dname;
private $conn;

function __construct(){
    $this->host = "localhost";
    $this->user = "root";
    $this->pass = "";
    $this->dname= "nast";
    $this->connect();
}

function __destruct(){
    $this->disconnect();
}

function connect(){

    if(!$this->conn){

        try{
            $this->conn = new PDO('mysql:host='.$this->host.'; dbname='.$this->dname.'', $this->user, $this->pass,
                                  array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
        }

        catch(Exception $e){
            die('Erreur:' .$e->getMessage());
        }

        if(!$this->conn){
            $this->status_fatal = true;
            echo'Connection Not Established';   
            die();
        }
        else{
            $this->status_fatal = false;            }
    }
    return $this->conn;
}

function disconnect(){
    if($this->conn){
        $this->conn = null;
    }
}
```

}

And named it "class.db.php". I got it from internet.

Then I tried to retrieve data from the database using the following code

```
require 'class.db.php';

$bdd = new db(); // create a new object, class db()
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM student';

$q = $bdd->query($sql);
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$r = $q->fetch();
echo $r['id'];
```

But it give the following error:

> Call to undefined method db::query() in C:\xampp\htdocs\prac\class.my.php on line 8.

Comment: You only have `connect` and `disconnect` methods, no such a method called `query`

Answer (score 1):

As what the `error` says, the function `query()` doesn't exist in your `db` class. Add a query function on your `db` class, something like this:

```
function query($sql){
   $this->connect(); // open a connection

   // do your codes here

   $this->disconnect(); // close the connection
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time "Dexterb"...as I said m new here in oop so would u kindly help me what to type at the code section this time. I would appreciate because m bit confused what to write here.....